# algorithm to patch values of an object with the latest patches in an ordered collection of patch sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have the following problem
At the  start I have an "object", which is, basically, a dictionary of string to value. I.e. this is not a .net object, it's a construct which works sort of like a javascript object.

Then I have an ordered collection of patchsets (each patchset has a "rank"). Each patchset is a set of patches. Each patch overrides the value of a single field in the "object" or any higher-ranking patch to that field. A patch in the first patchset will override the value of a field. If the next patchset contains a patch referring to the same field it will be overridden again etc.
My goal is to take the object and override its fields with the latest patches only.

e.g. given object like { price: 35, qty: 10 } and sets of patches:

1. [ { price: 40 }]
2. [ { qty: 15 },  { price: 20 } ]

at the end I should get { price: 20, qty: 15 }

I am sure there's an algorithm for that, but I am stuck. Any suggestions most welcome

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the collection from the end to the front and keep track of the fields already "patched" (for example using a Set), only set fields that weren't set before. You can further optimize if you count the number of set fields and as soon as that count equals the count of fields in the original object you're done.